# Export Outlook 2010 calendar to Thunderbird calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, thunderbird

I've made several web searches trying to find out how to import my Outlook 2010 calendar to Thunderbird, but can't find anything that works. I exported a csv file from Outlook and imported into Thunderbird, but got no error messages and no calendar.

I'm using the latest version of Thunderbird on Win 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps:

1) Download and install MailStore. Open the program. Make sure your email clients are closed (Thunderbird and Outlook 2010 in your case).

2) Run the "Archiving" tool. Choose your source. You can choose Microsoft Outlook.

3) Wait till it finishes the process. Depends on how much mail you have in Outlook.

4) Once done, it will show what folders have been archived in the Archive folders tree.

5) Right click any Folders, and click export and choose your destination. Such as Thunderbird.

6) Wait till the process is finished. And you should have all the mail in your Thunderbird as a separate local folder.

**Note:** MailStore, is a mail Archiving software, it will "Archive" your mail from any and most sources, including direct from the server (IMAP and POP3).

Hope this works

Thanks & Regards

Selah

Comment: Read this also if needed: http://www.ehow.com/how_6920878_import-outlook-calendar-lightning.html

Comment: MailStore did not import the Calendar from Outlook 2010. The ehow article apparently refers to a different version of Thunderbird. I'm using 45.1.1. There is no "import calendar" on the File dropdown. There is import under Events and Tasks. When I click it and select the file I created with Outlook nothing happens.

Comment: Plagiarism: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1090457  You should **always** link to your sources and put the quoted text in a quote block: http://superuser.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with Thunderbird and never getting the calendar data to import I discovered eM Client. The advantage with eM Client is that it more closely resembles Outlook than Thunderbird and was very easy to transition to.

I really, really appreciate all the help I received from Captian Ashish.

Comment: It's odd that you had to struggle with Thunderbird.  The process is pretty straightforward.  I switched to Thunderbird from Outlook and had concerns ahead of time, but the migration was surprisingly smooth and simple (following the procedure described in Captain Ashish's answer).  I wonder if you had an older version of Thunderbird that didn't have Lightning already bundled with it, or simply weren't displaying the calendar panel.  But glad you got your problem solved.